# How can I fix "W: <...> The repository is insufficiently signed by the key <...> (weak digest)" in my private repository?

Tags: apt, encryption, repository, gnupg

I maintain a series of private repositories.  The gpg keys used to sign the repo were made with "Key-Type: RSA" and "Key-Length: 4096".  The version of GPG used to generate the keys is 1.4.16 on Ubuntu 14.04.  The machine that complains has gpg 1.4.20 (on a beta of 16.04).

How can I fix "W: <...> The repository is insufficiently signed by the key <...> (weak digest)" in my private repository?

I'll admit that I don't konw too much about encryption, but I would have thought that 4096-length RSA key would have been sufficient.

Comment: This is on the signature hash function, NOT the key.  It's complaining about a SHA-1 signature hash on the thing, when it expects SHA-2.

Comment: You need to edit your key. This page more or less explains it. https://www.debian-administration.org/users/dkg/weblog/48

Leaving as a comment as it's not a proper aswer.

Answer (score 7):

The warning message is not about the encryption algorithm (4k RSA keys are considered totally fine and best practice right now). The *digest* algorithm is something else though: the hashing algorithm applied on the message body (in your case, the packages or package lists) which are then signed. GnuPG has rather conservative defaults to stay compatible, but those are slowly outpaced by progresses made in cryptanalysis.

You do not have to create a new key, but simply change the settings for GnuPG. The [proposals by the Debian-administrator blog are still fine](https://www.debian-administration.org/users/dkg/weblog/48) and help you setting reasonable defaults which are rather a little bit overcautious:

1. Set up the preferences to be used by GnuPG (for signing messages, encrypting to others, ...):

   ```
   cat >>~/.gnupg/gpg.conf <<EOF
   personal-digest-preferences SHA256
   cert-digest-algo SHA256
   default-preference-list SHA512 SHA384 SHA256 SHA224 AES256 AES192 AES CAST5 ZLIB BZIP2 ZIP Uncompressed
   EOF
   ```
2. Setting preferred algorithms in your key to be used by others (at the same time adds a new self-signature with the updated settings from #1 above):

   ```
   $ gpg --edit-key $KEYID
   Command> setpref SHA512 SHA384 SHA256 SHA224 AES256 AES192 AES CAST5 ZLIB BZIP2 ZIP Uncompressed
   Command> save
   ```

In future, digest algorithms considered secure should be chosen by GnuPG.

Comment: I'm consuming a repository created by another, and I can't get them to change the hash (they are "not supporting" my newer version of the operating system). Is there a way to get apt to ignore this problem?

Comment: GnuPG knows the option `--allow-weak-digest-algos`, but I'm not sure how you could pass it through `apt`. Notify the other party that MD5 is also broken for older and other operating systems.

Comment: I also added the 'digest-algo SHA512' config option, without it I still got a SHA1 signature. Verified with `gpg --verbose --verify Release.gpg Release`, adding '--verbose' makes it show the digest type.